# I want to run a code/function before all specs are executed in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

i have seen the available hooks in Cypress but what i want is run a piece of code/function before any of the specs are executed. how to achieved this in Cypress? Something like onPrepare(). Using 9.5.4 version with old config file.

Comment: You can use the `before` hook, which basically executes before any of the tests are executed.

Comment: @AlapanDas I think there's an important distinction here between "specs" and "tests". `before` doesn't run before all specs, it runs before all tests in one spec.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute a code **before any of the spec files** run, you can use the `on('before:run')` hook in your `plugins/index.js` file ([see the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api#Usage)).

```
module.exports = (on) => {
  on('before:run', () => {
    // do something...
  });
}
```

Comment: Note, it's `plugins/index.js` for Cypress v <10 and in Cypress v >10 you use the new config file `cypress.config.js`.

Comment: There's also a flag to set true `experimentalInteractiveRunEvents`.